# Is portable jndi syntax (EJB3.1) available across machines?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jndi, application-server

I was reading about "Portable Global JNDI names" in several articles, here and there for example, but I was unable to understand whether this syntax only applies to inbound machine lookups (or maybe inbound server lookup if the server is clustered).
I.e, does it only try to solve the problem of lookups between modules and apps on the same machine/server?
Because I keep seeing examples referencing to this feature and using `@Remote` which I would imagine can very well occur cross-machine/server.
If it indeed only resolves internal lookups to machine/server I'd appreciate it if someone could point me to the right direction with respect to how to use it with `@Remote` between servers (I'm guessing somewhere I need to prefix the host name).
Thanks,
Ittai

Answer (score 1):

You can call EJB component from another machine that's why @Remote anotation exists.Like

```
    String host = "10.1.1.111";
    String port = "3700";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
    "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
    props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", host);

    props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", port);

    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
    TestService ejb = (TestService)ctx.lookup("java:global/XXX/XXX/TestEntityFacade!com.test.service.TestService");
    ejb.findAll();
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should have mentioned I'm not interested in client lookup examples as my usecases are only between servers and via injection. I'm trying to understand how to map, in a non-propeitary manner, an ejb member to it's "origin"

Answer (score 1):

In that case you can use mention it in descriptor file then you can inject it using @EJB

```
@EJB(name="fooejbref")
private FooRemote fooRemote;
```

Within sun-web.xml :

```
<ejb-ref>
  <ejb-ref-name>fooejbref</ejb-ref-name>
  <jndi-name>corbaname:iiop:host2:3700#Foo</jndi-name>
</ejb-ref>
```

for details please please look this url http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#StandaloneRemoteEJB

Comment: Thanks again, that's the way I'm currently performing the lookup. I'm looking for a non-propreitary manner, i.e. no sun-web.xml/sun-ejb.xml but through ejb-jar.xml